# Как убрать последовательно повторяющиеся элементы из строки?

Tags: python

Решение 1:

```py
def func(s):
    st = ''
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i-1]:
            pass
        else:
            st += s[i]
    return st

s = 'xxxxxyyyyy'

print(func(s)) 
>>> xy
```

Решение 2:

```py
    from itertools import groupby 
    def func(s): 
        result_str = [] 
        for (key,group) in groupby(s): 
            result_str.append(key) 

    return ''.join(result_str)

s = 'xxxxxyyyyy'

print(func(s))
```

Какое решение выбрать?
Какие преимущества и недостатки у данных решений по отношению друг к другу?

Comment: почему не set(s) ?

Comment: если не трудно напишите ваше решение. Tак не понятно

Comment: это, собственно, все решение `print(''.join(set(s)))`

Comment: а если изменить стринг на 'xxxxxyyyyyxy'? В таком случае ваше ваше решение не подойдет. В условии задачи сказано: последовательные элементы

Comment: а! в этом смысле повторяющиеся

Comment: еще тогда можно регексом `(.)\1+` на `\1' :)

Answer (score 4):

Практика - критерий истины! (с) Маркс

```
def func1(s):
    st = []
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[i] != s[i-1]:
            st.append(s[i]) 
    return "".join(st)
    
def func2(s): 
    result_str = [] 
    for (key,group) in groupby(s): 
        result_str.append(key) 
    return ''.join(result_str)
    
def func3(s):
    return re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r"\1", s)

def func4(s):
    return "".join(unique_justseen(s))
```

---

замеры времени:

```
In [22]: s = "".join(str(i) for i in range(10**5))

In [23]: len(s)
Out[23]: 488890

In [24]: %timeit func1(s)
135 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit func2(s)
99.7 ms ± 311 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit func3(s)
92.6 ms ± 1.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [36]: %timeit func4(s)
107 ms ± 487 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**UPD:**  для более длинной строки (5.888.890 символов):

```
In [38]: s = "".join(str(i) for i in range(10**6))

In [42]: len(s)
Out[42]: 5888890

In [39]: %timeit func1(s)
1.67 s ± 25.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %timeit func2(s)
1.25 s ± 4.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [41]: %timeit func3(s)
1.18 s ± 2.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [43]: %timeit func4(s)
1.35 s ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: хоть и предложил regex, но немного неожиданно :)

Comment: @splash58, старик Маркс опять оказался прав! :)

Comment: ну, знаете ли. По ленину 'Когда Маркс говорит, что критерий истины есть практика, то он выражает этим, прежде всего, именно точку зрения относительности истины. С изменением содержания практики людей изменяется и их истина. То, что было истиною в пределах практики более узкой, перестает быть ею в практике более широкой, ' Кто знает,какие там входные данные :)

Comment: Померял по-другому https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryStableDebugmonitor

Comment: 4996, 3474, 5004 соответственно

Comment: Регулярки +- относительно первого решения, но 2 всегда быстрее

Comment: @вася, прелесть метода `%timeit` - в том, что он запускает команду много раз и выдает среднее значение и значение стандартного отклонения

Comment: @MaxU ну регулярки на больших данных теоретически не могут быть быстрее 2 решения, поэтому я засомневался и перемерял

Comment: @MaxU дайте воспроизводимую программу, померяю вашим методом у себя

Comment: @вася, `%timeit` - это "магический" метод, доступный из коробки в `ipython` и `Jupyter Notebook`

Comment: @MaxU поэтому я и не могу воспроизвести

Comment: @вася, уже проверил - см. UPD в ответе... Теория часто упирается в нюансы реализации)

Comment: @MaxU ну так вы запускаете на своей машине :) При желании можно закешировать всё заранее так, что выиграет заранее определённый метод

Comment: @вася, попробуйте запустить на своей, но с использованием `%timeit` и выложите свои результаты

Comment: @MaxU я же говорю, что не могу использовать `%timeit`. Мне нужна готовая программа, чтобы можно было протестировать

Comment: @вася, у вас нет доступа к `Jupyter Notebook` или `ipython` из стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: @MaxU что значит из стандартной библиотеки? Это же надстройка над питоном. У меня есть чистый `python3`, стандартная библиотека - это модули которые можно импортить без скачивания посторонних пакетов

Comment: @вася, https://www.dataschool.io/cloud-services-for-jupyter-notebook/

Comment: @вася можно поставить timeit и на чистый питонтолько вызов будет выглядеть немного иначе

Answer (score 2):

Второе, потому что многократное добавление в конец строки в питоне работает медленно из-за необходимости перекопирования.

А вообще лучше использовать готовые функции типа `unique_justseen()` из `more_itertools`.

Comment: да но во втором случае мы каждый раз делаем append, разве это не то же самое?

Comment: @nich123 во втором случае вы делаете добавление в лист

Comment: я понимаю, я имею в виду, что по затратам времени будет также

Comment: @nich123 нет, добавление в конец листа работает за константу амортизированную, а добавление в строку = перекопирование всей строки с добавленными символами, т.е. за длину строки

Comment: а если вот так сделать: `def func(s):
    st = []
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i-1]:
            pass
        else:
            st.append(s[i])
    return ''.join(st)`

s = 'xxxxxyyyyy'
print(func(s)) Заменить этим решение первое

Comment: @nich123 так можно, но читаемость второго метода всё равно лучше

Comment: это кому как, если groupby не знаешь как работает, тогда второй вариант совсем не понятен, а первый просто и ясно

Comment: @nich123 `groupby()` - стандартная функция языка. С таким аргументом надо всё писать только через циклы собственные, не используя возможности стандартной библиотеки. К тому же стандартные функции проще поддерживать. Скажем, для второго решения я не вижу улучшений, а первое можно упростить. Или если вам понадобится написать подобную `func` функцию, то достаточно будет заменить вызов `groupby()` на другую функцию из `itertools`, а в первом случае - полностью переписывать

Comment: `s = 'xxxxxyyyyylgyx'
list(groupby(s))' >>> [('x', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca1792c88>),
 ('y', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca1792f60>),
 ('l', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca1792c18>),
 ('g', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca3dc71d0>),
 ('y', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca3dc7908>),
 ('x', <itertools._grouper at 0x1aca3dc7ef0>)] вот не понятно почему groupby не группирует последние 2 знака(xy) c предыдущими (xxxxxyyyyy). Поясню, вторую функцию я не сам писал, по-этому и вопрос возник который я опубликовал

Comment: @nich123 так ваше первое решение же тоже не группирует

Comment: @nich123 если вам надо все повторяющиеся элементы в одну группу, а не только рядом стоящие, то просто `set()` используйте, как уже предлагали. Либо, чтобы сохранить порядок, `unique_everseen()` вместо `unique_justseen()`

Comment: нет я просто не понимаю как данная задача решается во втором случае, с первым все в порядке - я же его сам писал. А вот во втором: по идее groupby должна сгруппировать все элементы в группы, как же потом мы делаем append(key) если у нас в этой группе будут собраны все повторяющиеся элементы. А что же будет с теми которые стоят в конце? я просто не понимаю, почему Groupby не группирует во эти последние 2 элемента в предыдущие группы x и у

Comment: @nich123 не понял вопроса. Вы же сами показали выход `list(groupby(s))` - лист пар `(символ;обёртка содержащая информацию о количестве повторений этого символа)`. Далее вы просто берёте все символы подряд в этом листе по очереди, обёртка вам не нужна. Последние элементы тоже берутся, как и предыдущие, они не относятся к первым группам никак

Comment: @nich123 *я просто не понимаю, почему Groupby не группирует во эти последние 2 элемента в предыдущие группы x и у* -- потому что он так задуман, он и не должен их брать :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: если у нас есть xyz и мы группируем у нас получается три группы xyz. Если мы группируем xyzx у нас должно получиться опять три группы xyz тк последний x войдет в первую группу  x. Логично?

Comment: @nich123 зависит от определения группы. Для функции `groupby()` нелогично

Comment: скажите, а что это за groupby? это же не pandas? просто в сети много tutorials  по  pandas groupby  а вот по python groupby что то не не видно

Comment: @nich123 я же скинул ссылку на документацию https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby. Вот примеры использования https://stackoverflow.com/q/773, вот на русском https://pythonz.net/references/named/itertools.groupby/

Answer (score 0):

```
s  = "anoootoooonnnn"
k = set(s)
for i in k:
    while i+i in s:
        if (i+i) in s:
            s = s.replace(i+i,i)
print(s)
```